# I tried to make mutation test. In Intellij idea ı used pitest. But ı get an error message that the HTML file could not be created

Tags: intellij-idea, junit5, mutation-testing, pitest

Error: Could not find or load main class org.pitest.mutationtest.commandline.MutationCoverageReport
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.pitest.mutationtest.commandline.MutationCoverageReport

Comment: How do you launch a mutation coverage report? Describe the exact steps.

Comment: @Andrey  I could not find how the mutation report was integrated  I just pressed edit configurations and created pit runner. In the videos I watched, reports were obtained in this way.

Comment: Attach screenshots showing your steps including the run configuration. Do you use any 3rd plugin for Pitest?

Comment: A sample project would also help.